# How to rename a Trailhead Playground?

Tags: trailhead

I have a dozen of playgrounds (one per super badge) and wondering if it is possible to rename them and give a meaningful name (other than 'My Trailhead Playground #').
What are the steps to rename a playground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, From any hands-on challenge or project step,

- click the dropdown and click Manage my hands-on orgs
- click the  Pencil icon next to one of your Trailhead Playgrounds to rename it, or the  X icon to disconnect it. To connect a Trailhead Playground or Developer Edition org, click Connect an org.

For more detailed info read [Connecting, Disconnecting, and Renaming Trailhead Playgrounds](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/trailhead_playground_management/get-your-trailhead-playground-username-and-password)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do so.

From Settings page, just click on the edit action available with the playground, and rename it.

[image]